# Encrypt String with RSA and wrapped key in Java to files

Tags: java, encryption

I'm trying to encrypt some information in two different files, the first with a String encrypted in AES and the second with a Key encrypted with RSA, but I'm having some trouble making it work.

Here's my method:

```
public synchronized static void encrypToFile(KeyPair clauPublicaPrivada, SecretKey clauSecretaSimetrica) {
        String dades = null;
        byte[][] encWrappedData = new byte[2][];
        byte[] dadesAEncriptarEnByte;
        dades = extreureRutesDB();

        dadesAEncriptarEnByte = dades.getBytes();

        try {

            try {
                File file = new File(FITXER_DADES_TRIPULANTS_XIFRADES_AES128);
                File file2 = new File(FITXER_DADES_TRIPULANTS_XIFRADES_AES128_CLAUS);
                boolean fvar = file.createNewFile();
                boolean fvar2 = file2.createNewFile();
                if (fvar2) {
                    System.out.println("File2 has been created successfully");
                } else {
                    System.out.println("File2 already present at the specified location");
                }

                if (fvar) {
                    System.out.println("File1 has been created successfully");
                } else {
                    System.out.println("File1 already present at the specified location");
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println("Exception Occurred:");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
            IvParameterSpec iv = new IvParameterSpec(IV_PARAM);
            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, clauSecretaSimetrica, iv);
            encWrappedData[0] = cipher.doFinal(dadesAEncriptarEnByte);

            cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding");
            PublicKey clauPublica = clauPublicaPrivada.getPublic();
            cipher.init(Cipher.WRAP_MODE, clauPublica);
            encWrappedData[1] = cipher.wrap(clauSecretaSimetrica);



            CipherOutputStream cos = new CipherOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(FITXER_DADES_TRIPULANTS_XIFRADES_AES128), cipher);
            cos.write(encWrappedData[0]);
            cos.close();

            cos = new CipherOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(FITXER_DADES_TRIPULANTS_XIFRADES_AES128_CLAUS), cipher);
            cos.write(encWrappedData[1]);
            cos.close();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            System.out.println("menu 21(): FINAL");
        }

    }
```

The problem is that when I run it I get this error:

**java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cipher not initialized for encryption/decryption**

Any idea what I'm doing wrong and how to fix it?

Comment: @Bentaye That dupe is probably because `getOutputSize()` is called before the `init` method. It's based on trash code in the question, so it will not show any insight into the problem put down here.

Answer (score 2):

Reusing the same `Cipher` variable for different purposes is poor programming practice and confusing, and led you to these errors. You last left the `cipher` instance in `WRAP_MODE` prior to calling `doWrap()`. Then you supply the same instance to the `CipherOutputStream` constructors. Those require that the `cipher` object be in either `ENCRYPT_MODE` or `DECRYPT_MODE`.

Just call `Cipher.getInstance()` for every distinct use of a Cipher object. The overhead of that call will be insignificant in your program unless you're doing something very strange (and likely wrong) indeed.

Answer (score 1):

You're using the `CipherOutputStream` values incorrectly. To be precise, the way your code is setup you don't need to use them *at all*. These output streams are used to *encrypt* and *decrypt* the data.

However, the data is already encrypted when calling `encWrappedData[0] = cipher.doFinal(dadesAEncriptarEnByte);` and `encWrappedData[1] = cipher.wrap(clauSecretaSimetrica);`.

So you can simply directly write the result of those calls to file by just using the `FileOutputStream`.

---

The RSA-wrapped AES key will always be limited in size, so it doesn't make sense to stream that information. If the message (`dades`) is large you may want to use streaming, and use the AES based cipher instance to perform the encryption, without putting all of the plaintext and ciphertext in a byte array in memory. In that case the `CipherOutputStream` could make sense.